# Does FlashPlayer 10 support MP4 and AAC audio codecs in addition to MP3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I am developing an Audio Player application in Adobe AIR with Flex SDK 3.2. I wanted to know if i can play songs in other audio formats?

Comment: i tried converting an MP3 into AAC format using ffmpeg, and i am not able to play that file. so i am guessing only MP3 format is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Flash Player can play AAC but not AAC+. All the radio stations are using AAC+ because it is updated than AAC. Let me know if I am correct

Answer (score -1):

Although Adobe's site says, Flash Player 9 Update 3 onwards supports AAC and MP4 also, i am not able to play them when i tested. So i think its safe to say that, Flash Player will only support MP3 and WAV files to play sounds.

Comment: um mp4 is a video file wrapped with h.264 you need flvplayer to play it

Comment: What all audio files can it play then?